# Angularjs view multiple newlines from database in a column

Tags: php, angularjs

The database format is print out like this:

```html
<td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td>{{user.monday}}</td>
<td>{{user.tuesday}}</td>
<td>{{user.wednesday}}</td>
<td>{{user.thursday}}</td>
<td>{{user.friday}}</td>
<td>{{user.saturday}}</td>
<td>{{user.sunday}}</td>
<td>{{user.posiID}}</td>
```

But I want to print out like this

```js
$scope.gridOptions = {
rowHeight: 100,
columnDefes:[
{field: 'name'},
{field: 'cellTemplate: '<div class = "ui-grid-cell-contents">{{user.monday}}/{{user.tuesday}}/{{user.wednesday}}{{user.thursday}}/{{user.friday}}/{{user.saturday}}</td>/{{user.sunday}}'</div>'
}, {
field: 'posiID',
}]
};
```

I need help to make this work.  Thank you.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with php. With AngularJS, you can achieve the thing you want, using first code example you gave. why you should do it in 2nd way?

Comment: The 2nd way is the requirement, so I will have to do it.  AngularJS is not working for the 2nd way yet.